# Server keeps sending “text/html” data to the client

Tags: html, forms, frontend

I am submitting form data on the root route   `/` using the POST method. The form data is used by the server to fetch some data from other APIs. However, in the response , I am always receiving a `text/html` data and not `json` response.

**Form handler**

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    showSpinner()

    const tripName = document.getElementById('tripName')
    const tripDest = document.getElementById('tripDestination')
    const startDate = document.getElementById('fromDate')
    const endDate = document.getElementById('toDate')
    tripDetails.tripName = tripName.value
    tripDetails.tripDest = tripDest.value
    tripDetails.startDate = startDate.value
    tripDetails.endDate = endDate.value


    fetch('/',{
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body :  JSON.stringify({tripDetails : tripDetails})
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.headers.get('Content-Type'));
        res.text().then((data) => {
            return data;
        });
    })
}
```

*Response on client*

[image: ClientData]

However, when I open **Postman** to test my server side , I get the desired json response from the APIs.

**Server side code**

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    fetch(`http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?name=${req.body.tripDest}&username=${GEONAMES_API}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            destCoords.latitude = data.geonames[0].lat
            destCoords.longitude = data.geonames[0].lng
            return fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${DARK_SKY_API}/${destCoords.latitude},${destCoords.longitude}`)
        })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .catch(err => `Error >>> ${err}`)
        .then(data => {console.log(data);res.send(data)})
        .catch(err => `Error in sending data to client >>> ${err}`)

})
```

*Server side output*

[image: ServerResponse]

What exactly is happening here? I am unable to understand how the client is unable to receive the server json data .

*Also, I am using webpack to build my application . Am not sure if that could cause any issues since its the first time I am using it. The `dist` folder is created correctly and the app compiles successfully too.*

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
.then(data => data.json())
```

on form handler too.

Comment: That throws an `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error because the data type returned is `text/html` instead of json which is exactly my question .